# Is image scale the same as focal length?

Tags: reflection, telescopes

I am supposed to show using a diagram how image scale is related to focal length.

But my formula for image scale is
$$\text{image scale} = \frac{y}{\theta} = F$$
where $y$ is the image size on the detector, $F$ is focal length and $\theta$ is the angle the light ray makes when striking a concave mirror through the center.
But if image scale is equal to focal length then how can I "relate" them?

Comment: The capitalization in the question title was random and strange, so I fixed it. Please only capitalize the first word in the title and any proper nouns.

Comment: cheers, really useful

Comment: There was actually a [meta post about writing good titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: i will study it

Comment: Also fixed up TeX. Take a look at how I did it so you know how it works.

Comment: Something about the formula is fishy. $\text{image scale}$ should be dimensionless, but $y/\theta$ and $F$ have dimensions of distance. I think you just forgot a factor somewhere.